# Unity Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) not working when some arrow keys are also pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

Space bar key press detection doesn't seem to work when some combinations of arrow keys are also pressed.
Suppose a player controller like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Debug.Log("Space key pressed");
    }
}
```

Now when space bar is presed and...

- no arrow key is pressed at the same time -> it works (the trace is printed)
- a single arrow key is pressed at the same time -> it works
- up + right arrow keys are pressed at the same time -> it works
- left + right -> it works
- up + left -> it doesn't work (no trace is printed)
- down + left -> it doesn't work
- down + right -> it doesn't work
- up + down -> it doesn't work
- more than 2 arrow keys are pressed at the same time -> it doesn't work

If instead of `KeyCode.Space` you check for `KeyCode.X`, then it works when any 2 arrow keys are pressed at the same time, but it still fails when some combinations of 3 arrow keys are pressed at the same time.

I have seen this behaviour at least in Unity 2019.3.7f1 and 2019.4.16f1.

Comment: Some keyboards are limited in simultaneous key presses .. it is most probably related to that ...

Answer (score 1):

I would say it might be related to your keyboard being limited by silmultaneous key presses. If you have other keyboard, try it.

Or try to export the project and send it to someone and see if they have the same behaviour (First make it so the person you send it to will be able to "debug" it easily while playing the game).

Comment: You're right, it is a limitation of my keyboard. Apparently this limitation is called "keyboard ghosting". I didn't know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i solved my problem after I changed the keyboard with another one. Problem is directly limitation. In other words it is Rollover problem.